# Set an image at the bottom of kindle page in HTML for kindlegen

Tags: html, footer, kindle, kindlegen

I'm currently designing a title page for a MOBI file and using [kindlegen](http://www.amazon.com/gp/feature.html?docId=1000765211) to do it. I'm trying to center an image at the bottom of the title page (a logo), but I'm having trouble doing it. The [Kindle Publishing Guidelines](http://kindlegen.s3.amazonaws.com/AmazonKindlePublishingGuidelines.pdf) specifically don't let me use `position: absolute` or `position: fixed`, but I'm also not supposed to use white space (plus that doesn't work across all device sizes). Is there an easy way to force an image to the bottom of one Kindle page?